# How to check if a port is blocked by my ISP?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, portscan

My little backstory here is that I am trying to connect via ssh to a postgres remote database set up by heroku,

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-slippery-32494
psql: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "ec2-54-235-100-99.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (54.235.100.99) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I can not tell if my failures are due to something I have done, or the internet wifi itself. Considering I always develop at coffee shops like McDonalds, my only recourse is to find wifi networks which are not blocking ports.

How do you tell in ubuntu what ports are being blocked by the ISP?

Comment: you can use `nmap` command

Comment: The server is not set to allow remote access. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466190/cant-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432 and https://zaiste.net/postgresql_allow_remote_connections/ for some possible fixes.